# Mysql find duplicated on the first matched characters

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I want to pull out double records on the first matched four characters at the left or at first lines in MySQL.
how to make a SELECT?

```
id  name
1   1111q
2   1111
3   1111asdfgg
4   2222
5   2222ag
6   1111au
7   3333
8   5555
```

Something like:

```
id  name
2   1111
1   1111q
6   1111au
3   1111asdfgg
4   2222
5   2222ag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.*
from the_table t
     inner join the_table t2 ON left(t.name,4)=left(t2.name,4) and t.id<>t2.id
```

Join to the same table by LEFT 4 chars and exclude the same ID

Answer (score 0):

Remove my original answer as misread the question.

What you could do is add one more indexed column with the first 4 characters from string. You'll probably pre-process the strings with some other language. This way you can have working index also. By joining the same table in to calculation with subquery and join. You can then compare the counts. Even better would be if you can add some kind of comparison operator to subquery for searching only certain prefixes.

The solution using left is not bad at all, but it loses power of index when using function around field when comparing.

Here's working example from my solution. You can view the execution plan from the bottom.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d9cc/19